# Is Vegeta stronger than Beerus?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

During the Tournament of Power, Vegeta did overpower Toppo, who had destruction power. Beerus is similar to him, so maybe Vegeta is stronger than him too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Cell Max Arc, that is definitely not the case. Beerus was still able to toy with Vegeta as late as their last recorded clash in DBS Manga chapter 69. Vegeta powers up during Granolah Arc, but it would be far-fetched to claim a major breakthrough.